# How to effectively delete beginning and ending elements from a set in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

If I have set as follows:

```
set<int> dummyset = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

auto itr = dummyset.find(5);
```

And if I want to delete from `2 to 4`, I would type `dummyset.erase(dummyset.begin(), itr);`

But this takes linear time.

Assuming I intend to always want to delete two chunks from either end can I just move the beginning pointer or ending pointer (constant time) instead of deleting each element (linear time)?

Example:

```
begin     end
|           |
V           V
1  2  3  4  5

// Delete {1,2} and {5} by moving pointers

1  2  3  4  5
      ^  ^
      |  |
  begin  end
```

Comment: That can't happen, because the destructors of deleted elements still need to be called.

Comment: @Slava Linear like if dummyset.erase(dummyset.begin(), dummyset.end()); then if there are n elements, it would take O(n). But since I am effectively deleting all the numbers, why can't I just somehow set dummyset.begin = dummyset.end which would make this entire deletion operation constant time.

Comment: you can but destructors has to be called anyway

Comment: I know that here pointers are just set but actual data is still there, but that's ok for my use case since from the defined set perspective, it is empty.

Comment: @user3243499  because that would introduce a memory leak.  C++ is hard enough, we don't need to introduce ways to get standard containers to leak.

Comment: Store your ints in a sorted `std::vector` and use 2 iterators to define it's size and content. Wrap it up in your own container.

Comment: As long as you don't modify the underlying set, you could just keep track of your own start and end iterators.  Remove one or more elements at the start by advancing the start iterator, or setting it to the first element you don't want to erase.  Remove one or more elements from the end by decrementing your end iterator (set iterators are bidirectional), or setting it to the earliest element you want to remove.  You could wrap this in a class to manage the two iterators if you want.

Comment: btw did you really mean "effectively" in the title or rather "efficiently" ?

Comment: I took it to mean "effectively", as in make it act as if elements were deleted without actually deleting them (until the set as a whole is deleted).

Comment: Since both of them are sorted by their key; `set` and `map` are usually implemented as red-black trees. As this page (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) shows even if you erase last elements it has a logarithmic cost to find given key. If you want O(1) access you may want to use `unordered_set`, but as the name suggests it is unordered so... I suggest you to use a home made sorted-vector as @Slava suggests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, and you may not need to.

C++'s algorithms take iterator pairs. So, instead of `dummyset.begin()`, and `dummyset.end()`, pass them your adjusted iterators.

However if you are using `set` member functions (like member `.find()`), there's no way around it — you will need to actually erase. There's no way to tell those functions to temporarily act on a sub-range instead of the whole container (which I believe is what you were asking for).

Odds are this isn't as bad as you think. The implementation knows what it's doing, and *should* only rebalance its internal tree as much as is actually necessary, given a *range* of elements to remove.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I just skip actually erase and just reset the beginning pointer or ending pointer to itr which can be done in constant time?

For portable code, You would need to create a different container that exposes this functionality.

`std::set` intentionally restricts access to its underlying pointers, as manipulating them outside of [the established interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) would easily introduce object leaks, memory leaks, and undefined behavior that users of `std::set` are protected from.

Answer (score 0):

std algorithms are normally defined to operate on pairs of begin/end iterators. So you probably want to implement a view using a pair of iterators [in/de]cremented on demand.